# Add group to activity assignees

Tags: activities, groups

I want to assign everyone in a particular group to an activity when I create the activity.

Currently I only see how to add each one individually. This happens frequently enough that I would like to just assign to the group and have the contacts show up in the list of assignees, or use some other method to attain the same result.

When adding a new activity I can narrow the search to my group, but then I still have to add each one separately.

I tried searching for contacts in a group, then look for an action of "create activity" but that didn't show in my list of actions.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

CiviCRM 4.6.3 on Drupal 7.37 in a Linux Mint 17.1 VirtualBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to do this via Find Members or Advanced Search. Use either and select your Group. Search. Select all records. Under Actions find "Record Activities for Contacts". On the next screen you should see all members of your group. And there should be an option to "Create a separate activity for each contact."

Comment: I was looking for "Add an activity" or "create a new activity" so I missed "Record Activities". I am using activities more as a calendar than as a reporting mechanism, so the confusion was natural for me. Thank you.

Comment: there is some rework going on with the Actions dropdown and I think 'record activities' is one that is getting changed ... to 'add activity' ;-)